# Can we have different root directory for images in ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a web application in ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC. My all static files like JS, CSS, Images are in the `wwwroot` folder. I have another images folder named `loc_images` which contains around 500 000 images and it is placed in the root folder. It means `wwwroot` and `loc_images` folder are at same place. For some reason, I can not move this folder into `wwwroot`. In our application, user uploads the images and we will store them into `loc_images`, but I am not able to access these images if it is outside the `wwwroot` folder. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Copy these codes to the Configure section in Startup under the 
`app.UseStaticFiles()`

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
  FileProvider = new 
  PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), 
  "loc_images")),
  RequestPath = new PathString("/loc_images")
});
```